# "As of Date" Report logic

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I've been stuck on this issue for most of this morning...I am trying to work through a display issue with my SSRS report regarding my "As of Date". The data behind this report is loaded nightly, meaning the data is only as good as yesterdays actual date. My problem is that my report currently defaults the parameter to `=@AsOfDate = Today()`. 
However, in order for this to be accurately reflected, whenever a User wants to change the date on this report, I would need the "As Of Date" to always reflect yesterday. So if we ran this report for today 3/7/16, the Data behind the report is from 3/6/16 thus, the report should show "As of" 3/6/2016, and if they selected 2/29, on View Report, it should show As Of 2/28/16, etc.

My SQL statement in the report is using a column from my report table called CurrentDate which just holds the nightly load date. It states ...

```
WHERE @AsofDate = CurrentDate
```

Does anyone have any idea how I could accurately script this so that a User can always know that the data is from the night before?

Thank you!,

Comment: you should store the actual date of the last time you updated the table somewhere, so you can report that date instead of yesterday

Comment: You can use the DATEADD function in an SSRS expression.

Comment: @Lamak this makes most sense to do. I cannot use Today -1 as suggested because if a user picked 3/5/16, the As Of Date should display 3/4. My question is, if my AsOfDate is reflecting the CurrentDate column in my table, is there something more specific I can write to always have the AsOfDate in my header to show -1, regardless of that the user selects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting your AdOfDate to the default value for yesterday (calculated):

```
@AsOfDate = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, Today())
```

Otherwise, you could set your SQL query to do the same

```
WHERE AsOfDate = DateAdd(d, -1, GetDate())
```